# What's the type of a wrapper set returned by jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

with this:

```
console.log($('li:eq(1)'));
```

Chrome logs out:

```
[li, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "li:eq(1)", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
```

seems to be an array because there are [] around the result.

but:

```
console.log(typeof $('li:eq(1)'));
```

Chrome just logs out:

```
object
```

so what's the type of the wrapper set?

Comment: the type of an array is object see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof .. also the result of an jQuery wrapper is not a real array... it is a array like object

Comment: thanks, so chrome gives an array like object the []?

Comment: `typeof [] === "object"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are of type `Object` as well in Javascript so it is both. jQuery is an object that implements numerous array methods, stores matching elements in itself with array indexes and in many ways behaves like an array. You could think of it this way (grossly simplified to aid in understanding, *not how jQuery's constructor works*):

```
function $(selector, context) {
   var elems = (context || document).querySelectorAll(selector), 
       len = elems.length, 
        i = 0;

   for( ; i < len; i++) {
       this[i] = elems[i];
   }
   this.length = len;
   this.slice = Array.prototype.slice;
   return this;
}

console.log($('p').slice(0));
```

What you are seeing in your original `console.log` is the matching elements and a few other attributes jQuery exposes publicly.

Comment: thanks, how do chrome figure out the object is array like and gives it the [] instead {}? I mean for an object, aren't there should be {}?

Comment: I am not familiar with Chrome's particular implementation, but it is likely looking for certain methods or properties that are common to `Array` objects when deciding how to format console output. In Firefox the output is: `jQuery(p, p, p, p, p.newsletter-description, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p.privacy-policy-agreement, p.label-key, p.label-key, p.label-key, p.label-key, p.label-key, p.label-key, p.label-key)`